# Same programm works in C, but not in C++ (uses linux system calls)

Tags: c++, c, linux, system-calls

I'm supposed to write a (very basic) shell for linux for school. Currently i'm only trying to execute a programm with it at all (via fork and execv), and only plan on adding user-input later. I started writing in C (which i do not know at all/only know the some parts that it shares with C++) because  the slides were using it, but we can use either C or C++ and i planned on using C++ as soon as i learned how C handles/doesn't handle input/output/strings. (I took parts of the code (mostly lines where status, fork, execv, and wait are used) from the prof's slides and added parts of it myself.)
However, currently when using C the programm compiles, runs and seems to shows the expected output (printing out "testdesecho" by calling the echo function). But when copy-pasting the same code to C++ and trying to compile this, i get several errors (not just warnings) and so can't even compile the code.

This is the code

```
//#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>  
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <unistd.h> 
/*
readparsefunc() {

}
*/


int main() {
    int childPid;

    int status;
    char befehlstr[20] = "/bin/echo";                                                   //location              
    char* parameterstr[61] = { "echo", "testdesecho" };                                 //argv


    childPid = fork();

    //befehlstr = "";                                       
    //parameterstr = " ";
    //cout << parameterstr[1];
    printf("%d", childPid);     printf("<- childPid(test) \n");
    printf(befehlstr);          printf("<- befehlstr(test) \n");
    printf(*parameterstr);      printf("<- parameterstr(test) \n");

    if (childPid == -1) { printf("Konnte keinen neuen Prozess erstellen"); }            
    else if (childPid == 0) {                           
        printf("child process \n");

        int testintueberlagerung = 0;
        testintueberlagerung = execv(befehlstr, parameterstr);
        if (testintueberlagerung != 0) {
            printf("%d" "<- testueberlagerungswert \n", testintueberlagerung);
        }
        //execv(befehlstr, parameterstr);                   

        exit(0);                                        
    }
    else if (childPid > 0) {
        printf("parent process \n");
        wait(&status);                                  
        printf("parent process beendet sich nun auch \n");
    }

    /*
    while (1 != 0) {

    }
    */





    return 0;
}
```

And these are the errors:

```
testmitcanders.cpp:27:13: error: ‘fork’ was not declared in this scope
  childPid = fork();
             ^~~~
testmitcanders.cpp:41:26: error: ‘execv’ was not declared in this scope
   testintueberlagerung = execv(befehlstr, parameterstr);
                          ^~~~~
testmitcanders.cpp:51:3: error: ‘wait’ was not declared in this scope
   wait(&status);        
   ^~~~
testmitcanders.cpp:51:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘main’
   wait(&status);        
   ^~~~
   main
```

As far as i understand these all pertain to system calls and i do not understand why they would need to be declared in C++. but not in C?
(And how to declare them if i have to?)

Thanks for any help

Comment: So you try to complie `C` code with a `C++` compiler? These are different languages.

Comment: Did you include the necessary headers (`unistd.h` and `sys/types.h` per the Linux man page)? Older C specifications allow implicit function declarations; newer standards, and C++, do not.

Comment: Why are you commenting out this `//#include <unistd.h>`?

Comment: My view of your code was scrolled down and I didn't see the includes - but as Fiddling Bits asked, why is it commented out? You need it.

Comment: Note: C is *not* a subset of C++ these days. You *can* write code that is accepted by both a C and C++ compiler but does different things. You need to pick a language - they are *not* interchangeable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Older versions of C (that most compilers still support by default) had the concept of a default type for undeclared functions.  If a function is used before it is declared, C assumes the type of the function is `int (*)()`, i.e. a function that takes an unknown number of arguments and returns an `int`.  The actual types of the functions in question are more-or-less compatible with that definition so it seems to work.

C++ on the other hand does not have a default type for undeclared functions, so it throws an error right away when a function is used without being declared.

For the `fork` and `exec` functions you need to `#include <unistd.h>`, and for `wait` you need to `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <sys/wait.h>`.

Comment: C *had* the concept. It doesn't have any more.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Depends on what version of the C language OP is compiling with. And we don't know that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick & helpful response/explaination. Works now

Comment: @user Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you'd be surprised about how many compilers continue to support it even in standards modes

Comment: I have gcc 5.4.0 and it allows it (with warnings) even with `-std=c11 -pedantic`

Comment: @Mgetz they can support it. A compiler is allowed to successfully compile an invalid program. (provided that it issues required diagnostics)

Comment: As for claiming that the "version matters" it is like telling that you can write "þe olde pizza parlor" and that is proper English. Only the version matters.